# How would I display more than once?

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a dice game, which requires me to display 6 dice randomly. The problem I am getting is that when ever I push the button to execute the code, it will only display the randomly selected dice ONCE even if I tell it to choose 6 random dice. My question is: How would I repeat numbers in my code, so that the dice will display if the same die (single die) is selected more than once?

```
   if val == 1:
        show.blit(die1, (150,50))          
    elif val == 2:
        show.blit(die2, (250,50))
    elif val == 3:
        show.blit(die3, (150,150))
    elif val == 4:
        show.blit(die4, (250,150))
    elif val == 5:
        show.blit(die5, (150,250))
    elif val == 6:
        show.blit(die6, (250,250))
```

Here is the rest of the code for this code:

```
## gDieClass.py

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint

show = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
die1 = pygame.image.load('Dice1.tga')
die2 = pygame.image.load('Dice2.tga')
die3 = pygame.image.load('Dice3.tga')
die4 = pygame.image.load('Dice4.tga')
die5 = pygame.image.load('Dice5.tga')
die6 = pygame.image.load('Dice6.tga')


class graphic_die(object):

    # class that displays a graphical rep. of 6 sided die

    def __init__(self, size, surf, pos):

        # define some values
        self.SURF = surf
        self.POS = pos
        self.SIZE   = size


        self.__DIESURF = pygame.Surface((size, size), flags=SRCALPHA, depth=32)
        self.__DIESURF.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))

        self.value = 1

        ## Dice Colors
        self.die_color  = (0,0,0,0)

        self.__RADIUS = self.SIZE//10
        __HSIZE  = self.SIZE//2
        __QSIZE  = self.SIZE//4
        self.PIPRAD = self.SIZE//10

        # create Pips/Dots in standard places

    def __drawBackground(self):

        # create square with rounded corners
        pygame.draw.circle(self.__DIESURF, self.die_color, (self.__RADIUS, self.__RADIUS), self.__RADIUS)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.__DIESURF, self.die_color, (self.SIZE - self.__RADIUS, self.__RADIUS), self.__RADIUS)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.__DIESURF, self.die_color, (self.__RADIUS, self.SIZE - self.__RADIUS), self.__RADIUS)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.__DIESURF, self.die_color, (self.SIZE - self.__RADIUS, self.SIZE - self.__RADIUS), self.__RADIUS)

        pygame.draw.rect(self.__DIESURF, self.die_color, Rect((self.__RADIUS, 0), (self.SIZE - 2 * self.__RADIUS, self.SIZE)))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.__DIESURF, self.die_color, Rect((0, self.__RADIUS), (self.SIZE, self.SIZE - 2 * self.__RADIUS))) 

    def __makePip(self, point):

        # helper function to make pips
        pygame.draw.circle(self.__DIESURF, self.pip_color, point, self.PIPRAD)            

    def setRandValue(self):
        self.value = randint(1, 6)

    def __drawValue(self, val):

        self.__drawBackground()

        # Creates PIPs at Value
        if val == 1:
            show.blit(die1, (150,50))          
        if val >= 2:
            show.blit(die2, (250,50))
        if val >= 3:
            show.blit(die3, (150,150))
        if val >= 4:
            show.blit(die4, (250,150))
        if val >= 5:
            show.blit(die5, (150,250))
        if val >= 6:
            show.blit(die6, (250,250))

    def display(self):
            self.__drawValue(self.value)
            self.SURF.blit(self.__DIESURF, self.POS)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.  `dice` is plural; `die` is singular; would you please edit your answer so that I know which you mean.

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious? die+die+die+die+die+die=dice. There are 6 different die, which in total produce the term: Dice.

Comment: You say "_...same dice is..._".  `dice` is plural, but `is` is for something singular.  You are apparently talking about a single die.  If you misuse `dice` once, I see no reason to assume that you don't misuse it in other places.  I am simply asking you to edit your answer, so that I know in each case if you are actually talking about more than 1 die.

Comment: I am talking about 6 different die. A total of 6 dice :).

Comment: please add more code. what val is. how you are representing your dice. Also, from the piece of code i see. At any time only one die shall be shown. because for the whole block the variable val can hold only one value. May be you are running this block in a loop ? will the loop assume all the six valued from [0,6]

Comment: You say `dice` in more than one place.  You display 6 dice randomly.  That is perfectly clear. ...it will only display the randomly selected dice ONCE... That also, I think, is perfectly clear.  ...same dice is selected... Not clear.  You could say "same dice are" or "same die is", but "same dice is" is incorrect English.  Seeing that you use the plural word when you mean the singular, I am now unsure about your previous uses of the word.

Comment: Zondo thank you for trying to help.

Comment: When you say "display 6 dice randomly", what do you mean? Do you mean that there are 6-sided (cube shaped) dice and you need to choose one value for a single cube? Or do you mean that you must display the randomized faces of six different cubes, next to each other?

Answer (score 0):

if die1, die2, etc each represent a die, well you are only showing only one of those with that code, try with

```
if val >= 1:
    show.blit(die1, (150,50))          
if val >= 2:
    show.blit(die2, (250,50))
if val >= 3:
    show.blit(die3, (150,150))
if val >= 4:
    show.blit(die4, (250,150))
if val >= 5:
    show.blit(die5, (150,250))
if val == 6:
    show.blit(die6, (250,250))
```

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't seem to work. Thank you for trying :).

Comment: you modify self.value at some point, right? because in your code you set it to 1 in the init method only and in no other place you touch it...

Comment: Could you show me what you mean? I am a bit confused.

Comment: self.value = randint(1, 6)

Comment: This is where it would change the value.

Comment: yeah, but have to call `setRandValue` to that to happen or assign it directly, if you do that fine, maybe you are unlucky and randint give you the same value several times in a row, it could happen, try assign it a value directly like 6 and see. (if you don't do neither of that well...)

Comment: I will try this! Thank you.

Comment: So values do assign properly, but it appears that the dice will display behind the other if it is selected more than once. I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: try changing their position or size, other than that I can not help you with pygame because I don't have it...